# How to solve PHPSpread sheet not found error

Tags: php, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create an excel sheet using PHP. When I call the API from localhost, it gives me

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'vendor\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet' not found in /var/www/html/sti/svr/excel/sheet.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/sti/svr/excel/sheet.php on line 8` error.
```

This is my file:

```
<?php

// require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); 
use vendor\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use vendor\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

// Creates New Spreadsheet 
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

// Retrieve the current active worksheet 
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

// Set the value of cell A1 
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'GeeksForGeeks!');

// Sets the value of cell B1 
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'A Computer Science Portal For Geeks');

// Write an .xlsx file  
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

// Save .xlsx file to the current directory 
$writer->save('gfg.xlsx');

?>
```

**Updated :**

I created another folder called trail and installed the composer and replaced this code inside trail/vendor/ ,

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
?>
```

my folder structure

[image: folder structure]

when i called the file from localhost, it gives me

`` Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/trail/vendor/sheet.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/trail/vendor/sheet.php on line 3 `` error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try uncomment the first line you commented

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
```

Comment: this gave me `Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied in /var/www/html/sti/svr/excel/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php on line 409
`error. I'm using Ubuntu OS. how to solve this?

Comment: how you are using zip archieve ?

Comment: i didn't get it . could you please repeat it ?

Comment: still i get the same error :( . Shall i update the structure of my folders?

Comment: Yes some other issue is there. Though your main issue is resolved

Comment: now i have created a new file in another new directory and places the php file inside vendor. It gives me Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') . can you see my updated answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204596/discussion-between-amit-sharma-and-f-a-sulaiman).

Comment: let connect in chat. please click on above link